# Leibnitz rule for fractional derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I need to estimate the following norm
$$\Vert fg\Vert_{H^{\frac{1}{2}}(\mathbb{R}^3)}$$
Is there some product rule for the fractional derivative?

Comment: I was looking at fractional derviatives a while back and found this note by Kobelev very useful. http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1202/1202.2714.pdf

Comment: What do you want to estimate it with? Are there some norms of $f$ and $g$ that you know and would like to use? What regularity do $f$ and $g$ have? There are many possible estimates you could make.

Comment: I'd like to know if there exists some kind of product rule for fractional derivative

Comment: Would you be satisfied with an estimate $\|fg\|_{H^{1/2}}\lesssim\|f\|_{?}\|g\|_{?}$ for some norms? If you need to estimate the integral, it's not clear that you should actually use any kind of a product rule for fractional derivatives. You don't even need to define a fractional derivative to define the space $H^s$ for $s\in\mathbb R$. You seem to have two questions (how to estimate an integral and is there a product rule); could you elaborate on how they are connected or which one you eventually need?